Wireguard & Megafon
Друзья, кто понимает в настройках, расскажите мне пжл, есть ли способ запустить Wireguard VPN под Мегафон? Что-то сотовый оператор там у себя настроил и теперь определяет траффик с wireguard и блокирует его нафиг.
Единственная статья, которая объясняет что как и почему на Хабре, из которой я понял, что Мегафон определяет, но вообще не понял, что нужно делать, чтобы починить.
Имеется свой VPS (Германия) - настраивал по подсказкам в сети. Есть conf файл для wireguard
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ***
Address = ***
DNS = 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4

[Peer]
PublicKey = ***
PresharedKey = ***
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = ***:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25

Использую его дома на роутере Кинетик для обхода блокировки нужных сайтов, иногда под виндой и раньше использовал в телефоне на андроиде вне дома- теперь не могу.
Дома все работает отлично на местном провайдере. На мегафоне ни черта. Помогите пжл

попробуйте еще развернуть OpenVPN, я использовал его с мегафоном и работало отлично, в существующих множественных блокировках непонятно что и где отваливается

Спасибо , видимо придется попротовать openvpn

не могу осилить настройку  openvpn :(

нашел тут инструкцию https://www.linuxshop.ru/forum/f7/t41686-problemy-v-rabote-openvpn-i-wireguard-kak-obojti.html , но не понимаю, что есть ListenPort  и где его взять в случае с win10

Я ставил OpenVPN из под докера и установка в несколько шагов заняла пару минут, по мануалу без каких-либо знаний в этой теме.

победил.

в конфиг wireguard в разделе [Interface]  добавляем строку ListenPort = 12345 после строки address
ставим под винду программу Nmap
выполняем команду из CMD раз 10 подряд:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\nping.exe" --udp --count 1 --data-length 16 --source-port 12345 --dest-port [порт vpn] [ip сервера vpn]
запускаем wireguard

ВУАЛЯ!!
Спасибо всем причастным!
В место пунктов 3 и 4 лучше просто в конфиг wireguard клиента в разделе [Interface]  добавить строку:
PreUp = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\nping.exe" --udp --count 1 --data-length 16 --source-port 12345 --dest-port [порт vpn] [ip сервера vpn] --unprivileged
